# Graph Theory [vertex connectivity]

Tags: graph-theory

Let  $κ$ denote the vertex connectivity of a graph. 
Let $Q_n$ denote a hypercube graph. where Number of vertices = $2^n$  and number of edges = $n 2^{n-1}$
Ik that $κ(Q_n) = n$ , what is the kappa of $κ(Q_n^c)$ .
My guess is that the complement $Q_n^c$ has $κ(Q_n^c) = 0$ , because by definition of complement and a hypercube graph. 
Is my guess correct ? How do I prove it formally ? 
Or are there special cases when vertices are even and odd ? 
Thankyou.

Comment: The graph complement of $Q_n$ with $n\geq 3$ is connected, so no.  Consider two vertices.  If they were already not adjacent in the original graph then they are adjacent in the complement.  If they were adjacent in the original graph, then you can find some vertex not adjacent to either in the original graph, showing there is a path between them in the complement.  You should formalize *why* we know there to be such a vertex not adjacent to either (*note: such a vertex doesn't exist for when $n\leq 2$*).  It also remains to show what the actual vertex connectivity is.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about how connectivity relates to the number of distinct disjoint paths we can find between vertices?

Comment: Yep , for n <= 2 , kappa is 0 . Well ,Degree of $Q_n^c$ is $2^n - n - 1$ , so for n>= 3, It is connected and have used Dirac's theorem to prove that is connected , so is kappa in the range of 1<= kappa <= 2^n - n -1 ? I am not getting the exact formula. @JMoravitz

Comment: Dirac's theorem is fine, but it could have been proven to be connected easily without it.  Remember that there is an easy bijection between vertices in $Q_n$ and binary sequences of length $n$.  Vertices are adjacent if their corresponding binary sequences have exactly one difference between them.  Vertices are not adjacent if their corresponding sequences have two or more differences between them.  For example, the vertices $(0010)$ and $(0011)$ are adjacent in the original graph, but both are not adjacent to $(1100)$ as well as $(1110)$ and $(1000)$ etc...

Comment: Continuing with this way of looking at the graph, consider using [Menger's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem).  The graph is at least $k$-connected if you can find at least $k$ disjoint paths between any two vertices.  How many disjoint paths can you find between two vertices that were originally adjacent in $Q_n$?  How many disjoint paths can you find between two vertices that were originally non-adjacent in $Q_n$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I understood what you are trying to say , but I am finding trouble finding those paths :( , So is it like for adjacent ones ...it has n -1 disjoint paths and for non - adjacent it has n - ( n -1 ) .Ugh , idk how I formulated those ! But I guess if the adjacent ones have k disjoint paths => the non adjacent ones have n - k disjoint paths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incomplete answer:**

Consider working with the interpretation of the cube graph $Q_n$ as instead of the set of $n$-length binary sequences.  Two distinct sequences are considered "adjacent" if and only if they differ in exactly one entry.  Two distinct sequences are considered "nonadjacent" if and only if they differ in two or more spots.

Consider two adjacent distinct sequences.  Without loss of generality, let them be $(100000\dots 0)$ and $(000000\dots 0)$.  Any sequence with at least two $1$'s in the final $n-1$ spots will be non-adjacent to both, any sequence with exactly zero $1$'s in the final $n-1$ spots will be *equal* to one of these, and any sequence with exactly one $1$ in the final $n-1$ spots will be adjacent to at least one of these.

Let us count how many sequences fall into the first category by instead calculating how many fall into the second two and subtracting from the total.  There are two sequences which end in $n-1$ zeros.  There are $2(n-1)$ sequences which end with $n-2$ zeroes and one $1$.  There are then $2^n-2-2(n-1)=2^n-2n$ different sequences in the first category.  Each of these give rise to a distinct path of length $2$ from $(1000\dots 0)$ to $(0000\dots 0)$ in our complement graph.

If we were to have any additional paths in our complement graph which are disjoint from any of these paths already mentioned, they would need to travel solely through vertices that are adjacent to at least one of but not both of our vertices in our original graph.  For example $(1000\dots 0)\mapsto (0100\dots 0)\to (1010\dots 0)\to (0000\dots 0)$.  We recognize that any such path must use at least two such vertices, one that starts with a $1$ and one that starts with a $0$, and we recognize that we can construct disjoint paths of length $3$ using each exactly once.  Travel from $(1000\dots 0)$ to $(0\dots 0\underbrace{1}_{k}0\dots 0)$ to $(1\dots 00\underbrace{1}_{k+1}\dots 0)$ to $(0000\dots 0)$, or in the case $k=n$ from $(1000\dots 0)$ to $(000\dots 01)$ to $(1100\dots 0)$ to $(0000\dots 0)$.  There are exactly $n-1$ such paths we created.

As such, we can find exactly $2^n-2n+n-1=2^n-n+1$ disjoint paths between two vertices in the complement graph that were originally adjacent in the original graph.

---

Now for the challenging part: counting how many disjoint paths we can find between two vertices that were originally nonadjacent.  There is an obvious path of length $1$ between each pair, but surely there are more.

Let us consider the problem of counting the number of paths between $(1111\dots 1)$ and $(0000\dots 0)$, starting with counting the number of paths of length $2$.  Any sequence with at least two $1$'s and at least two $0$'s will be non-adjacent to each.  Assuming $n\geq 4$, we have that any sequence that does not have at least two $1$'s or at least two $0$'s violated exactly one of those conditions and not both.  There are $2^n$ total sequences, $n+1$ of them violated the condition that at least two $1$'s be present and $n+1$ violated that at least two $0$'s be present.  As such for $n\geq 4$ there are $2^n-2n-2$ different vertices simultaneously nonadjacent to both of $(1111\dots 1)$ and $(0000\dots 0)$.  (*As an aside, this is true for $n=3$ as well, as that would be $2^3-2\cdot 3-2=0$*).  As such, for this specific pair of vertices, we can find at least $2^n-2n-2$ distinct disjoint paths of length $2$ between them.

As such, there are at least $2^n-2n-2+1=2^n-2n-1$ paths between two polar opposite nonadjacent vertices in the complement graph.

---

Still left to complete:

- How many paths of length $3$ can we make between $(1111\dots 1)$ and $(0000\dots 0)$ which avoided using any of the vertices used in the paths of length $2$?

(*In the case of $n=3$, there are two such paths*)

- Are we able to conclude that we don't need paths of length $4$ or more to continue building our collection of disjoint paths?

(*It is worth remembering that there cannot possibly be more than $2^n-1$ disjoint paths as that would require more vertices than exist, so regardless of answer here there cannot be many paths that we missed*)

- Can all pairs of originally non-adjacent vertices have at least as many disjoint paths as $(1111\dots 1)$ and $(0000\dots 0)$ have?

(*In the case of $n=3$, this is correct*)

Once we have finished these last details, we may then apply [Menger's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger's_theorem) to conclude that the vertex connectivity is the minimum of the maximum number of disjoint paths between two vertices.

---

In the case of $n=3$ we have $\kappa(Q_3^c)=3$ and in terms of asymptotics assuming my intuition is correct we should have that $\kappa(Q_n^c)\sim 2^n$ (*technically unproven in my post as of yet*).